# how to redirect python's subprocess.Call methods output to a file and not console?

Tags: python, sql-loader, subprocess

I am using python's Call method in subprocess module to execute a sqlldr command

```
from subprocess import call

retcode = call([self.COMMAND, self.CONNECTION_STRING, "control=" +self.CONTROL_FILE, 
            "log="+self.TEMP_LOG_FILE, self.MODE , "data="+loadfile])
```

When i run the above script the output of the sqlldr command gets printed to the console which i wan to redirect to a file or ignore it. since sqlldr also writes to the log specified.

i tried something like this, to redirect the output to a file, but throwing error at this line

```
retcode = call([self.COMMAND, self.CONNECTION_STRING, "control=" +self.CONTROL_FILE, 
            "log="+self.TEMP_LOG_FILE, self.MODE , "data="+loadfile, "> discard.log"])
```

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a file for writing and pass that as the stdout keyword argument of `subprocess.call`:

```
with open('stdout.txt', 'wb') as out:
  subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'], stdout=out)
```

(`subprocess.call` accepts the same arguments as the [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) constructor.)