# How to direct standard output to string instead of file with python subprocess.call

Tags: python

The following questions regard how to write subprocess.call to output files.

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532455/how-to-redirect-pythons-subprocess-call-methods-output-to-a-file-and-not-consol)

[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884000/how-to-redirect-pythons-subprocess-call-output-to-file)

Is there away to redirect standard output of subprocess.call() to  a string  object in python, instead of having to create a file? For example, I would like to call the md5sum command, and simply save the results as a string. Is there a way to forgo the file making step?

Comment: Why down votes? Seems to me that research was performed, and the question is clear and useful. Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `subprocess.check_output()` in a similar fashion (it has the same argument structure as `call`) and it will return the output as a byte string for you.